# permutations of a 3 object

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Help please,

Exercise: Work out the full multiplication table for the set of permutations of three objects.

I know there are $6$ permutations.
$(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), (2,1,3), (1,3,2)$ and $(3,2,1)$.

However, I don't know the order. I know order is very important.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, some of the permutations you've written down are the same. Second, you've missed all the transpositions and the identity. You say there are 6 elements, so try to find all of them. Then you can work on the multiplication table by doing it out explicitly.

Comment: Why is order important? I mean, if you want, usually you would write it in alphabetical order, but it's not important "just because it's important"...

Comment: Actually the book gives away the 6 permutations, so I don't understand why it would be repeated.

Comment: @IanColey: There is no repetition. For example, $(1,2,3)$ is intended to be the permutation that sends $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $2$, and $3$ to $3$. (Not a good choice of notation! Conflicts badly with the standard cycle notation.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas It's [one-line notation](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/One-line_notation_for_permutations) which is quite standard in combinatorics.  But I think I've usually seen it with square brackets to avoid confusion with cycle notation.

Answer (score 2):

For exemple $$(2,1,3)\circ(3,2,1)={ {1\, 2\, 3} \choose {2\, 1\,3}} \circ {{1\, 2\, 3}  \choose {3\, 2\, 1}}$$ Since for this multiplication
$$1\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 2$$
$$2\rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3$$
$$3\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1$$
we have $$(2,1,3)\circ(3,2,1)={ {1\, 2\, 3} \choose {2\, 3\,1}}=(2,3,1)=(123)$$
Order of  $(1,2,3)$ is 1.

Order of $(2,3,1)$ is 3 (because $(2,3,1)\circ(2,3,1)\circ(2,3,1)=(1,2,3)$).

Order of $(3,1,2)$ is 3 (because $(3,1,2)\circ(3,1,2)\circ(3,1,2)=(1,2,3)$). 
Can you finish?